# Cannot hide panel on (document).ready

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, panel

I have a simple html that has a table inside of a panel:

```
 <div id="MainContent_pnlMsgDisplay" style="position:absolute; width: 500px; border-width: thick; left: 500px; top: 230px;">

    <table style="width:300px;" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" style="width:120px; margin-left: 20px">
        <span id="MainContent_lblMsg" style="color:Red;"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" style="width:120px; margin-left: 20px">
        <span id="MainContent_lblUpdateMessage"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>   

</div>
```

I just do not need to show this panel first time I load the document, so I do something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#MainContent_pnlMsgDisplay').css('style', 'display: none');

 });
```

But I still see the table? Is table supposed to be hidden if it is inside of a hidden panel?

Comment: `.css('style', 'display: none')` is incorrect. Refer to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

```
$('#MainContent_pnlMsgDisplay').hide();
```

or the [.css( propertyName, value )](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) takes a style name and its value as the 2 params

```
$('#MainContent_pnlMsgDisplay').css('display', 'none');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use css like this

```
$('#MainContent_pnlMsgDisplay').css('display', 'none');
```

[**`.css()` documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/css/)